# Como abrir un Frame en una ventana Toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola buenas soy nuevo en la programacion y como primer proyecto quise crear como una base de datos de la nomina de los empleados y a su vez una interfaz principal para seleccion la operacion a realizar ya sea Agregar registro nuevo, modificar o borrar, y en una segunda ventana queria hacer las operaciones no mas que no encuentro la manera de poder hacer visible un Frame en la segunda ventana, hace rato segun avia escrito hasta un Menu y tampoco aparecia y ya me quede sin ideas, si me pueden ayudar explicandome como poner Frames una ventana TopLevel me seria de mucha ayuda gracias

'''

```
from tkinter import *

import sqlite3

from tkinter import messagebox

>#---------------Ventana 1--------------
root = Tk()
root.title("Nomina")
root.geometry("300x350")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

>#--------------Frame 1------------

class Ventana(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master= None):

        super().__init__(master, width=280, height=330)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.widgets()


    def widgets(self):

        self.boton_crear=Button(self, width=15, height=3, text="Registro nuevo.",         
                         command=crear_ventana)
        self.boton_crear.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="e", padx=0, pady=25)

        self.boton_editar=Button(self, width=15, height=3, text="Editar registro")
        self.boton_editar.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="e", padx=0, pady=25)

        self.boton_eliminar=Button(self, width=15, height=3, text="Borrar registro")
        self.boton_eliminar.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="e", padx=0, pady=25)

miId=StringVar
>#Ventana Nueva
class crear_ventana():

    def __init__(self):
        self = Toplevel(app)
        self.title("Agregar Registro - Nomina")
        self.geometry("300x350")
        widgets_ventana2(self)

    def widgets_ventana2(self):

        self.idLabel=Label(self, text="ID:")
        self.idLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", padx=10, pady=10)

        self.cuadroID=Entry(self, textvariable=miId)
        self.cuadroID.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)







app = Ventana(root)
app.mainloop()
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas teniendo el error porque estas superponiendo la clase Toplevel a la de crear_ventanas. Entonces cuando se llama al self.widgets_ventana2() realmente python intenta buscar ese método en la clase Toplevel y no en la de crear_ventanas
La solución quedaría tal que así

```
class crear_ventana():

    def __init__(self):
        self.top_level = Toplevel(app)
        self.top_level.title("Agregar Registro - Nomina")
        self.top_level.geometry("300x350")

        self.widgets_ventana2()

    def widgets_ventana2(self):

        self.idLabel=Label(self.top_level, text="ID:")
        self.idLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", padx=10, pady=10)

        self.cuadroID=Entry(self.top_level, textvariable=miId)
        self.cuadroID.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Si sabes el concepto de herncia (que lo has usado en la clase Ventana), esto se puede hacer más fácil y leíble. La clase crear_ventanas podría heredar de Toplevel:

```
class crear_ventana(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(app)
        self.title("Agregar Registro - Nomina")
        self.geometry("300x350")
        self.widgets_ventana2()

    def widgets_ventana2(self):

        self.idLabel=Label(self, text="ID:")
        self.idLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", padx=10, pady=10)

        self.cuadroID=Entry(self, textvariable=miId)
        self.cuadroID.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio de mucho, ya no recordaba en si que era la herencia jaja

Comment: De nada :) Acepta mi respuesta si ha resuelto la pregunta, creo que me ayudaría. Y suerte con la app!!